# Accessing a public table from Fusiontable from java program

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-fusion-tables, google-api-java-client

I am trying to access a public table from google FusionTable. So all i need is a Simple API Key.
Please let me know if i am making the Fusiontables object in a right way.

---

fusiontables = new Fusiontables.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, null).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new FusiontablesRequestInitializer(ClientCredentials.API_KEY)).build();

Am i missing something in creating an object of Fusiontables. Please guide me, Thanks

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem?